# Passive voice or present continuous?

Tags: passive-voice, verb-forms, present-continuous

I have been asked “How’s your English?”

I answered: “It is **improved** slowly,” but I have read that I must say “It is **improving** slowly.”

But I don’t think the second is correct, because you improve it (by) yourself and not by another body.

Comment: Please punctuate and capitalize to make this intelligible.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking of the transitive form of the word, but ***improve***, used intransitively (without an object), means ["to increase in value, excellence, etc."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/improve)

Answer (score 1):

"*it is improved*" can be used to describe a state, but "*slowly*" can only describe an action. You can't refer to 'it' as both a state and an action.

To get round that, you have to use an active verb such as "*improving*" to match the *"slowly*".

A minor problem is your use of present simple passive. "*It has improved*" is more natural.